# Unrecognized option 'filter_complex' using avconv

Tags: libav

I would like to mix two audio files using avconv. In the documentation I found the following way of implementing this:

```
avconv -i INPUT1 -i INPUT2 -filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT
```

However, when I'm trying to run this I get the following errors:

```
Unrecognized option 'filter_complex'
Failed to set value 'amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3' for option 'filter_complex'
```

I have been searching for a solution for quite some time, but couldn't find anything.

I have version 0.8.3-4:0.8.3-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 of avconv. Do I need to change anything in the configurations or use a different version of avconv? Is there another way in which I could mix the audio files?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

In some versions, the "complex filter" can specified using the "-filter:v" option, like:

```
avconv -i INPUT -filter:v amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 2):

Today I was reviewing this problem also and the final solution was just to [download a fresh static copy of ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/static/64bit/) and forget about the problem...

It seems that avconv doesn't implement -filter_complex, although the manual states that it does.

Answer (score 2):

Version problem you have to update ffmpeg with latest.
but we can also  `-vf` instead of `filer-complex` like:

```
ffmpeg -i new1.mp4 -vf "movie=wlogo.png [watermark]; [in][watermark] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:10 [out]" -strict experimental output.mp4
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use libav9 probably. Version 9.9 had been released recently.